# Kobuki error , Kobuki/Watchdog no signal in rqt. Kindly help me out?

Tags: kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with turtlebot 2 , I have searched everywhere about this problem. After launching oslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch the terminal works fine but turtlebot does not move or show any kind of movement. When I ran ''rosrun rqt_robot_monitor rqt_robot_monitor'' it is giving me these two errors , kobuki error and kobuki/watchdog no signal. Kindly help me out as I am a totally new to this thing.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244230/kobuki-error-,-kobuki/watchdog-no-signal-in-rqt.-kindly-help-me-out-!/) by [owais2k12](https://answers.ros.org/users/28041/owais2k12/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you're launching the telop applications but do not have the drivers for the kobuki started. For the teleop_keyboard launch files to be useful you need to also be running `roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch` in another terminal simultaneously.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@tfoote is right did you launch `roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch` ?

and did you heard the bring-up sound from Kobuki, when it get start, Kobuki could have a bringup sound.

if Kobuki cannot bring-up, you probably need this

http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_bringup...

udev rules,
. /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash

```
rosrun kobuki_ftdi create_udev_rules
```

---

Originally posted by [DinnerHowe](https://answers.ros.org/users/26306/dinnerhowe/) with karma: 188 on 2016-09-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2